# Not Printing desire output using arrays and reading from files

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, java.util.scanner

The program function is to read from two separate text files, One text file is called gifts(random names) and cost(total cost for each day). I have to print if the user input is 3, it will print the 3 lines with the cost of those 3 days. Additionally, I have to print the total cost of the 12 days.

My code

```
import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class GiftsTwelveDays{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] gifts = new String[12];

        double[] costGifts = new double[12];

        String total = new String();

        //Following code reads the Gifts.txt file

        File file = new File("gifts.txt");

        try 
        {
            Scanner scannerFile = new Scanner(file);

            while (scannerFile.hasNextLine()) 

            {
                int i = scannerFile.nextInt();

                String present = scannerFile.nextLine();

                gifts[i - 1] = present;

            }

            scannerFile.close();

        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 

        {
            System.out.println("File not Found.");
        }



        //This reads the cost and stores in array of double

        File file1 = new File("cost.txt");

        try 
        {
            Scanner scannerFile = new Scanner(file1);

            while (scannerFile.hasNextInt()) {

                scannerFile.next();

                if(scannerFile.hasNextInt())

                {

                    int i = scannerFile.nextInt();

                    double cost = scannerFile.nextDouble();

                    costGifts[i-1] = cost;

                }

                else
                {

                    scannerFile.nextInt();

                    total = scannerFile.nextLine();

                }

            }

            scannerFile.close();

        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {

            System.out.println("File could not be found");;

        }

        //following gets user input and runs

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        NumberFormat money = NumberFormat.getInstance(); //for format with comma

        money.setGroupingUsed(true);

        double costDay = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter the day:");

        int choice = userInput.nextInt();

        userInput.nextLine();

        if (choice < 1 || choice > 12)//runs if choice is invalid

        {

            System.out.println("Invalid Choice");

        }

        else

        {

            System.out.println("Your gifts for the day " + choice + " are: \n");

            //calculates the day cost and prints gift simultaneously

            for(int i = 0; i < choice; i++)

            {

                System.out.println((i + 1) + gifts[i]);

                costDay = costDay + costGifts[i];

            }

            //prints the calculated cost.

            System.out.println("\nCost of Day: $" + money.format(costDay));

            System.out.println("\nTotal Cost for Twelve Days: $" + total);

        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter the day:
3
Your gifts for the day 3 are: 

1 Patridge in a Pear Tree
2 Turtle Doves
3 French Hen

Cost of Day: $0

Total Cost for Twelve Days: $
```

gifts.txt

```
1 Patridge in a Pear Tree
2 Turtle Doves
3 French Hen
4 Calling Birds
5 Gold Rings
6 Geese-a-Laying
7 Swans-a-Swimming
8 Maids-a-Milking
9 Ladies Dancing
10 Lords-a-Leaping
11 Piper
12 Drummers Drumming
```

cost.txt

```
220.13
595.13
776.63
1376.59
2126.59
2516.59
15641.59
15699.59
23252.43
33252.43
36056.83
39094.93
```

Comment: What's the desired output then?

Comment: Cost of Day is 0, but my text file has 12 numbers and the total cost doesn't display meaning adding all the 12 numbers equals the total cost of the 12 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you were scanning the costs.txt document had some issues.

There is no Integer type value in the text , so the hasNextInt() function will always return false to you.

Instead of summing up all the values in the total variable you were inputting the last value read from the file in a String variable , furthermore you were expecting an Integer value again so the String was left empty , that is why you were not seeing anything on the output and only the last value after the fix provided above.

I altered your code like this

Firstly i changed the type of Total from String to Double

Then i changed your scanning section from this :

```
 while (scannerFile.hasNextInt()) {

            scannerFile.next();

            if(scannerFile.hasNextInt())

            {

                int i = scannerFile.nextInt();

                double cost = scannerFile.nextDouble();

                costGifts[i-1] = cost;

            }

            else
            {

                scannerFile.nextInt();

                total = scannerFile.nextLine();

            }

        }

        scannerFile.close();
```

To this :

```
int i = 0;
        while (scannerFile.hasNextDouble()) {


                double cost = scannerFile.nextDouble();
                costGifts[i] = cost;                    
                i++;                    
                total += cost;                                               

        }

        scannerFile.close();

    }
```

Now the total is calculated correctly while you are reading each line and you are also making sure that you are not skipping any lines.

Comment: Thank it worked, Ive been struggling with this project so much. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your use of scannerFile.hasNextInt() when evaluating cost.txt. The file cost.txt only contains doubles, so that first call returns false, so the costGifts[] array is never populated.

Try using scannerFile.hasNextDouble() instead and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: It did fix the issue but it prints the last number is this case 39094.93 and the total doesn't show either

Comment: Instead of using int i = scannerFile.nextInt(), initialize a variable that starts at 0 outside of the while, and increase it after you add each value. This will also remove the need to use i-1 as your index. 

Also make sure to accept this as the answer if it is a correct solution to your problem.

Comment: I still have the same problem. D: